# How to display ads on Canvas element in Android with no XML used?

Tags: java, android, xml, canvas, ads

I am developing a game and I need to display ads on top of the main canvas.

I have a MainActivity class starting entire application:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle sis) {
        super.onCreate(sis);
        game = new Game(this);
        setContentView(game);
}
```

and then Game class holding most of the calculations and canvas things. 
However, the game runs on a separate thread from the UI thread and uses SurfaceHolder to fire up the thread, etc.

```
private SurfaceHolder holder;

private Thread drawThread;

public Game(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
        mainCanvas=new Canvas();

    }
    public Game(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }
    public Game(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }
    @TargetApi(21)
    public Game(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }
```

And then it all fires up the drawing thread, like so:

```
 boolean drawing = true;
    /**
     * Creates a new draw thread and starts it.
     */
    public void startDrawThread(){
        if (surfaceReady && drawThread == null){
            drawThread = new Thread(this, "Draw thread");
            drawingActive = true;
            drawThread.start();
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Started");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Stops the drawing thread
     */
    public void stopDrawThread(){
        if (drawThread == null){
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "DrawThread is null");
            return;
        }
        drawingActive = false;
        while (true){
            try{
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "Request last frame");
                drawThread.join(5000);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "Could not join with draw thread");
            }
        }
        drawThread = null;
    }
```

Question is, how do i get the ads to show on my canvas? I am not using any XML code, everything is generated programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out myself.
I created an XML class which fires up instead of

```
super.onCreate(sis);
    game = new Game(this);
    setContentView(game);
```

and startup code is like this:

```
 super.onCreate(sis);
    game = new Game(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

I have very simple XML file:

```
   <com.canvas.game.Game
    android:id="@+id/game"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_banner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Hope this helps someone along the way.
Thanks anyway!